# How to convert API response "File Stream with content type jpeg" to image file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Task :  Save the Image from API response file stream object.

I am able to receive the response from API.  But I am unable to save the content as a Image file.

I have tried the following options.

1. response is converted to byte array.
2. The following code:

   ```
   using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(arr))
       {
           System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream);
           Img.Save(Server.MapPath("StudentImages") + "//test.jpg");
       }
   ```

But it is raising the

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

exception.

Please help us.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Hi, System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream); in this line i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting current location in the stream liek this:

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(arr))
{
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream);
    Img.Save(Server.MapPath("StudentImages") + "//test.jpg");
}
```

Or using the `position` property:

```
mStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and getting the following error. "Parameter is not valid." in second line (System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream);)

Comment: @Venkateswararaoakula As you are new here, please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you to some answers, but it would be even kinder to accept the best answer (this is up to you of course!). Voting (once you crossed the 15 rep points yourself) and accepting are the way to say Thx on SO. [Please read this: someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)